# Javascript "this" context when the callback is an object method

Tags: javascript, this

I have two objects: myapp and dom. The code on plunker was taken (but a little simplified) from Stoyan Stefanov book "Javascript patterns".

http://plnkr.co/edit/FutgitMBlnrYfBKuL0Ig?p=preview

```
var myapp = {};
var color = "purple";
myapp.color = "green";
var dom = {};
dom.color = "red";

myapp.paint = function (node) {
    console.log(this.color);
};


dom.findNodes = function (callback) {
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback();
    }
}


dom.findNodes(myapp.paint);
```

According to the book:

> If you call findNodes(myapp.paint), it won’t work as expected, because
>   this.color will not be defined. The object this will refer to the
>   global object, because findNodes() is a global function. If
>   findNodes() were a method of an object called dom (like
>   dom.findNodes()), then this inside of the callback would refer to dom
>   instead of the expected myapp.

On my code I expect to get color "red", because i call object method dom.findNodes instead of global function. So why do i always get global variable with a value "purple"? Thanks!

Comment: There's tons of similar questions already on SO, some of which have very good answers. Please look around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function:

> ```
> function (callback) {
>     if (typeof callback === "function") {
>         callback();
>     }
> }
> ```

… doesn't use `this` so it doesn't matter if you call it as `findNodes` or `dom.findNodes`.

The `this` you care about is here:

> ```
> myapp.paint = function (node) {
>     console.log(this.color);
> };
> ```

When you call `myapp.paint()`, `this` is `myapp`.

When you call `callback()`, `this` is `window` (in a browser, when not in strict mode).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what about the following phrase?

_If findNodes() were a method of an object called dom (like dom.findNodes()), then this inside of the callback would refer to dom instead of the expected myapp._

The question is about book example...

Comment: @ИванЯрославцев — That's simply wrong. The value of `this` inside the callback depends entirely on how the callback was called. It isn't affected by how the function calling the callback was called.

Answer (score 0):

You could either bind the "this" object like:

```
dom.findNodes(myapp.paint.bind(this));
```

Or suppose this as a parameter and call the paint function with it:

```
dom.findNodes = function ( callback, thisObject )
{
    if (typeof callback === "function")
    {
        callback.call(thisObject);
    }
}

dom.findNodes(myapp.paint, myapp);
```